# Form '#theme' preprocess doesn't invoke

Tags: forms, theming

I have form where `'#theme' => 'ebanq_transfer_theme'`. Template file is rendered but preprocess hook doesn't invoke. Any ideas?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function ebanq_transfer_theme() {
    return array(
        'user_accounts_form' => array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'template' => 'user-accounts-form',
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'ebanq_transfer') . '/templates',
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Accounts form preprocess.
 */
function ebanq_transfer_prepocess_user_accounts_form(&$vars) {
    $form = $vars['form'];
    dpm($form);
}
```

Comment: Did you copy this code from your module? If so you have a typo ... preprocess not prepocess

Comment: Yeah, it is so. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

> ebanq_transfer_preprocess_user_accounts_form(&$vars)

must be called

> template_preprocess_user_accounts_form(&$vars)

So the Drupal bootstrap / hook system will know that.

Comment: Why not theme_preprocess_user_accounts_form(&$vars)? Or is it a same way?

Comment: @misha-from-lviv No. You're confusing theme functions with preprocess hooks.